# Strapi admin panel keeps on loading after registration

Tags: strapi

I tried to deploy my strapi application on my server, which was successful as the registration panel popped up. But after creating an admin user, the loading screen appeared and keeps on loading. So I don't get to see the Strapi admin dashboard.

I'm using PostgreSQL for this one so I verified that the user was created. Locally I did not experience any problems.

I was thinking if it might have something to do with the .env variables? For example, in my local environment the .env file was created automatically, but I don't know how to fill in those variables in my production environment.

These are mine server.js and admin.js files:

[server.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVXCP.png)

[admin.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZO8w.png)

Also, there aren't any errors both in console and on the server...

I tried to change my .env variables used in the admin.js file but there is little documentation about the production application, so I don't really know what I need to do.

Comment: Which platform or VPS did you use to host your Strapi app? AWS, DigitalOcean, Heroku or?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @khangnd I used Hetzner cloud to host the app, since my other applications work with Hetzner as well. For the first deployment of the app I did not change anything special in the code of the Strapi template.

Comment: You need to add `URL` to your server.js, otherwise strapi doesn’t know where it is: https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/configurations/server#available-options

Comment: I did so, but now I'm getting: GET mydomain.com/admin/telemetry-properties 401 (Unauthorized)